# Ubuntu isn't loading anymore

Tags: 12.04

I've been dual booting Windows 7 & Ubuntu 12.04 LTS since last 3 months. I made partitions and all and it was working excellent during these couple of months. But suddenly ubuntu has stopped to boot. During booting i get the prompt to select either windows or ubuntu, then some kind of boot message is displayed, but after that it displays just nothing.

I can log into windows and when i check in My Computer the partition i made for Ubuntu is just invisible. I dedicated around 180 gb of my hard disk for ubuntu but now it shows nothing.

I mostly use ubuntu now so help me as most of my files are now on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all: keep calm and try to backup your most value data with the help of a live CD and an external harddrive.
That ubuntu partitions are not shown in windows is normal. Windows only knows Windows and ignores anything else not coming from Redmond.

Comment: Unless he allowed it to format linux partitions. It only asks once...

Answer (score 0):

As mondjunge said, first backup your data, either using, a live CD or if you are using windows, you can use, "Diskinternals linux reader" free application to navigate linux partitions.

For the issue relating to booting of ubunut, you could fix with "Boot-Repair" follow the link below:

[Auto Boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Hope it helps.